# Loop in Jquery by using eq

Tags: jquery

I want to use loop to display the title of link .  is included in div "test" I write code like this:

```
$("#test a").each(function (index) {
    alert($("#test a:eq(index)").attr("title"));
})
```

I get the result "Undefined". If I change

```
alert($("#test a:eq(0)").attr("title"))
```

it works normal. Anybody can help me???. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

`.each` is already looping through the `a` elements, just alert the title:

```
$("#test a").each(function () {
    alert( this.title );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using `index` as part of the string. You have to concatenate the *value* of `index`:

```
$("#test a").each(function(index) {
    alert( $("#test a:eq(" + index + ")").attr("title") );
});
```

---

But you don't really need that. You could simply use the `this` keyword:

```
$("#test a").each(function() {
    alert( $(this).attr("title") );
});
```

The `this` keyword will always be the current node in the loop.

Comment: Why use `$(this).attr("title")` when `this.title` is faster and more compact.  jQuery should only be used when it's actually better.

Comment: @jfriend00 - absolutely. Was just using the OP's code, as I figured that it was just an example, and that he would then want to do some other jQuery-y stuff.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of clarity I always specify both the key and value parameters. k being the index count and v being the selector object e.g

```
$("#test a").each(function(k, v){
    alert($("#test a:eq(" + k + ")").attr("title"));
});
```

[Heres a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/VXZyG/)

Comment: This is NOT the preferred way to do this.